What is the Biblical basis for a historicist reading of the seven churches in Revelation?
The second and third chapters of Revelation include a series of seven letters to seven churches in Asia. A historicist interpretation understands these seven churches as representing seven ages of church history. I'm interested in where this idea comes from. It is plain that the messages of the letters are relevant to a wider audience than the churches to whom each was originally addressed, since there is the repeated admonition, "he who has ears, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches". However, I don't see where in the text one would find a chronological understanding of the letters. What is the Biblical argument used to support the interpretation of the seven letters representing seven successive stages of church history?


OP: What is the Biblical argument used to support the interpretation of the seven letters representing seven successive stages of church history?

Here's the Biblical argument as popularized by Hal Lindsey in The Late Great Planet Earth.  (to be clear, I do not agree with this understanding)
This biblical verse sets the outline.

Write the things which thou hast seen, and the things which are, and the things which shall be hereafter; Rev 1:19

What was, what is, what will be.  This is the instruction about which to write.
What was is chapter one wherein John describes what he sees.
What is are the letters to the seven churches; that is, letters to the church age in chapters two and three.
What will be is after the church age, since what is, is the church age.

After this [literally after these things] I looked, and, behold, a door was opened in heaven: and the first voice which I heard was as it were of a trumpet talking with me; which said, Come up hither, and I will shew thee things which must be hereafter. Rev 4:1

This is the rapture.
After these things, the church age, the what is, ends at the rapture, the door in heaven open, a voice of the trumpet, calls to come up to heaven, to show what will be hereafter.  Revelation now turns to the what will be, which is basically tribulation period.  Churches are not mentioned again until the end at Rev. 22:16.
So, the view that the seven letters to currently existing churches that represent seven church ages and perhaps some that overlap is built into the sequence of what John saw and wrote in chapter one, the what is of the 7 churches, and the what will be after the church age.

This is the supporting argument I have heard most often.+1

So let me make sure I understand this: The argument is that the overall structure of Revelation is chronological, and this must therefore translate down to the level of finer details, including that the seven churches are in chronological order representing the church age?

Correct.  Revelation is chronological as outlined right in chapter 1:19. The 7 churches are church ages (the what is when John wrote church age).  After the rapture (come up here) is the what will be of the tribulation that is the 7 seals that lead to the 7 trumpets that lead to the 7 bowls..  These judgments/wrath are in chronological order of the seals, trumpets, and bowls; likewise, the 7 church ages are chronological.

That is... one of the arguments of all time, for sure.

Biblical Basis?The "biblical basis" for any interpretation of holy Scripture is found in the verses themselves---hence the use of the word, "biblical."
So, what did the LORD (Alpha and Omega) reveal in the Bible concerning these Seven Churches? We read:

I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last; What thou seest, write in a book and send it unto the seven Churches which are in Asia---unto Ephesus, and unto Smyrna, and unto Pergamos, and unto Thyatira, and unto Sardis, and unto Philadelphia, and unto Laodicea. (Revelation 1:11)


We can deduce from these instructions that the Revelation was sent to existing churches in the Roman province of Asia.  There is not the slightest hint of a consecutive history imagery! All the churches existed in the first century during the life-time of John.
The descriptions given about each local Church fits the culture, geography, and history of the first century! (See any traditional commentary or historical geography book on Revelation.)
Each letter to the Churches ends with the same phrase dealing with "overcoming", implying the same time of ending.

Hermeneutically, without engaging in eisegesis, it can be concluded that each of the local churches were contemporaneous with the ministry of John the Revelator, and were located in Asia.
Extra-biblical SourceResearch reveals that Sources
outside the Bible present a "consecutive historical approach" to these verses. An example is the presentation in C.I. Scofield's Reference Study Bible (1917) While not all, but most eschatologies based on Dispensationalism, include this type of historical interpretation.
It is true that the admonitions in each letter do have a wider application to believers in all churches in every generation. But historicist Dispensationalists seem to find particular descriptions that apply to only certain eras in church history. While other interpreters see these characteristics in all Generations throughout church history, the historicists magnify them in particular eras only.
Thus writes Grant R. Osborne, in his REVELATION, BAKER EXEGETICAL COMMENTARY ON THE NEW TESTAMENT,A 2002; p. 105:

There is, however, one more theory, belonging to classical dispensationalism, that these letters are not so much letters to individual churches (Bullinger 1909:68 would say these are not letters at all but are entirely prophetic) as a historical plan prophesying the seven future periods of church age (so Chafer, Walvoord).


Therefore, Ephesus stood for the early church, Smyrna the period of persecution in the patristic era, Pergamum the time of Constantine, Thyatira the Middle Ages, Sardis the Reformation, Philadelphia the eighteenth and nineteenth centuries (missionary outreach), and Laodicea the modern era (time of growing apostacy before the return of Christ).


Thomas (1992:508-10) outlines the three major arguments for this position: the moral conditions are so varied that they cannot simply describe the church of John's Day; the prophetic atmosphere extends beyond the first century; and the later three churches especially extend all the way to the parousia; the correspondence between the periods of church history and these seven letters cannot be just accidental.


HOWEVER, the details of the seven churches do not fit merely the epochs of the church. It is clear from the text that the characteristics of these letters were meant for all the churches of Asia Minor and indeed for all periods of church history...Therefore even dispensational scholars like Thomas (see his excellent discussion, 1992:511-15) opt for the view that the letters address historical situations in Asia Minor, not periods of church history. (p. 105)

ConclusionIt is hard to find a "purely biblical basis" for this historical interpretation of the seven church letters. Much is founded upon one's understanding of History, and interpretation of church history in particular. This leave a great fluidity of application, and opens the door of speculation that many do not close very tight.

Extra-biblical sources - indeed.  Appreciate the clarity your answer has brought to this subject.

The quote provided answers the question, showing how comparatively recent this historicist interpretation is (7 churches chronologically representing 7 church dispensations, or eras). And it needs to come with a flashing red warning light, accompanied by sirens, if possible. The principles given to all 7 churches apply to all Christians at all times, but modern dispensationalism is so fixated on chronological sequence, and literal interpretations, it misses the point of those sacred, eternal principles.
